# I am trying to create a socket in python 3 but i get this error, even when i copy code stragte from the web

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am new an am learning network programming and I have a problem, whenever I try to create a socket, even how a tutorial tells me to, I get this error when I run the code, and also it has a problem with how I imported sockets and threading. This project is a basic server that will send all the errors and high resource usage from a desk workers machine to an old tower I have, this is for monitoring purposes and because we just upgraded to windows 10 in the office and I am getting a lot of complaints about slow and not working programs and machines. Thanks a bunch.

**The Error:**

```
harrison@dev-box:~/Desktop/dns# python3 socket.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/root/Desktop/dns/socket.py", line 4, in <module>
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

**The Code**

```
import socket
import threading

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 504))

sock.listen(1)

log = open("log.txt", "w")

def handler(connection, address):
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        for connection in connections:
            connection.send(bytes(data + "Hello World"))
        if not data:
            connection.remove(c)
            c.close()
            break

while True:
    connection, address = sock.accept()
    cThread = threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(connection, address))
    cThread.daemon = True
    cThread.start()
    log.write(connection + "/n" + address + "/n")
    data, addr = sock.recv()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename your `socket.py` into something else like `mysocket.py`, which will avoid to conflict with the default python library `socket`.